# How to install MATLAB Engine API for Python with Python 3.7?

Tags: python, matlab, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-kernel

I have a Linux OS and I want to install MATLAB Engine API for Python to use MATLAB on the Jupiter notebook. I am following the [steps of installation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/install-the-matlab-engine-for-python.html) from here but it seems that the Matlab engine API only is not working with Python 3.7 (but it is capable with python 3.6) my final goal is to use Matlab using [imatlab package](https://github.com/imatlab/imatlab) in [Jupiter notebook](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html). Is there anyone who ever been able to install MATLAB Engine API for Python with Python 3.7?

thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

- Before installing [matlab_engin](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/install-the-matlab-engine-for-python.html) you may just change **setup.py** file. 
  *(you should change the permission of this file, for example:* `chmod 777 setup.py`*)*. Add '3.7' in list of supported version:

```py
_supported_versions = ['2.7', '3.4', '3.5', '3.6', '3.7']
```

- Install in shell

```sh
python3.7 setup.py install
```

- Matlab kernel also should be install.

```sh
pip install matlab_kernel
```

- Then in file **/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matlab/engine/__init__.py** 
  comment`raise EnvironmentError("Python %s is not supported." % _version)` and add `_PYTHONVERSION = 3_6`. In result:

```py
if _version in _supported_versions:
    _PYTHONVERSION = _version
else:
    _PYTHONVERSION = '3_6'
    #raise EnvironmentError("Python %s is not supported." % _version)
```

Now you can start *jupyter* and choose *Matlab kernel*

Comment: running the `python -mimatlab install` to install matlab kernel spec. returns this error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matlabengineforpython3_7'` I should mention that I changed the `_supported_versions = ['2_7', '3_5', '3_6', '3_7']` too.